# How to add conditional form to a dropdown box on SquareSpace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, squarespace, vs-web-site-project

I am looking to have the form hidden, until the user selects "Other" from the dropdown box, this is my code so far, but the form wont show up.

```
<style>

/* This hides the prefooter area */

#preFooter {
   display: none;
 }

  #text-yui_3_17_2_1_1592488106653_18663-field {display: none;}

  #text-yui_3_17_2_1_1592488106653_17373-field {display: none;}

</style>

<footer>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

$('#select-yui_3_17_2_1_1592428429486_20443 input').click(function() {
  selection = $(this).val();                                                 
  if (selection == 'Other (please specify)') {
  $('.form-item').show();
  }};
</script>
 </footer>
```

Any ideas on what I should change??
Thank you

Comment: I don't see where `selection` variable is written. It appears here out of nowhere. Also your jQuery selector looks weird, what is this `input]` at the end of the selector? Why do you need this?